# Text classification on feature vector X with multiple vs. merged columns

Tags: text, nlp, classification, text-classification

I am working on text classification problem where I have around 95 data points and the data looks like this (only two dummy entries shown):

```
                           |   ID    | Location |  Emails     |
                           ------------------------------------
                           |  AZ12   |    UK    | Lorem Ipsum |
                           |  MR34   |    USA   | Lorem Ipsum |
```

In my current approach, I have merged the data in .csv, space delimited (shown below) and I am using only one column to do text-classification.

```
                                |     Merged_columns    |
                                -------------------------
                                |  AZ12 UK Lorem Ipsum  |
                                |  MR34 USA Lorem Ipsum |
```

This approach seems to work for me and I am getting around 70% of accuracy with test data.

Now I am thinking of performing text classification on multiple columns of my feature vector (X) instead of merging all columns of X vector into one column (like by performing feature engineering on individual columns of X vector and then concatenating the transformed vectors. The approach has been mention in this article as well : https://towardsdatascience.com/natural-language-processing-on-multiple-columns-in-python-554043e05308).

Now my question is : When it comes to NLP, are both approaches equivalent theoretically. Should the later approach yield any better/worst results than my former approach.
Thanks.